# Redis is blocked from external connections before getting restarted

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, redis

In my Ubuntu virtual machine in Hyper-V, I have installed Redis and it runs on startup (by doing `sudo systemctl enable redis`) and I have configured it to `bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.10.100` in the config (the 2nd IP is for internal connections across the local network).

The problem I have is that when I start the virtual machine, it won't allow connections from other local computers (connecting from `192.168.10.100`). But when I restart Redis by doing `sudo systemctl restart redis` it only then allows.

This problem is **not** because I forgot to restart Redis when adding `192.168.10.100` to the Redis bind.

Comment: In init script did you run redis after the second IP is up?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I haven't modified `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` so I'm not sure. Looking at that file I don't see where I could bind it. It does have `--supervised systemd`. It also says `--daemonized no` but in `redis.conf` it's set to yes

Comment: You do not get my point. You set second IP. Is it run redis after the set of this second IP?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm not sure, how can I check?

Comment: If you run second IP in systemd you should have in redix `Requires=secondip.service`
and/or `After=secondip.service`

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm not very experienced with linux so I'm not sure how can I run the second IP in systemd. Looking at the redis.service I see there's `After=network.target` not sure how I can see what's inside network.target.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138911/discussion-between-parpar8090-and-romeo-ninov).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because redis is started before your interface is actually up and configured, I've been dealing with the same issue

I've added `After=network-online.target` to my redis.service file, this should actually wait until the network interface is "up", instead of just initialised (which may or may not include an IP). This might work for you

Unfortunately I haven't been able to test this yet, but I will update this comment once I've rebooted this system at least once